# Property 'address' does not exist on type 'CoinFlip & { deploymentTransaction(): ContractTransactionResponse; }'

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I have the following code:

```
async function main() {
  const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

  const CoinFlipFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('CoinFlip');
  const CoinFlipContract = await CoinFlipFactory.deploy()
  console.log(await CoinFlipContract.address)
}
```

and get the above listed error. When I query the object via `console.log(CoinFlipContract)`,
address is not only listed as a property in the ABI, but has a value:

```
filters: {},
  _runningEvents: {},
  _wrappedEmits: {},
  address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  resolvedAddress: Promise { '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3' },
  'consecutiveWins()': [Function (anonymous)],
  'flip(bool)': [Function (anonymous)],
```

as listed in a similarly titled question, I tried

```
console.log(await CoinFlipContract.getAddress())
```

but this returns the same error.

I can, however, call the functions actually defined in the contract's .sol file and they work fine (`.consecutiveWins()` and `.flip(bool)`

What's really perplexing me is that vs code is suggesting `getAddress` like it's a known method of the contract object, but it returns an error when I try to call it. What is going on? This is deployed on localhost via `npx hardhat node`. I am using ethers 5.7 and have used this same code with a different contract type and it worked just fine.